# List builder : how to make the first element different?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a list (dynamically, throught the result of an HTTP request to an API) but I want to add a 'add' card first, before the others elements.
Like this :

[image]

I'm building this with a builder
But the way I do it is not good, there's a problem.

[image]

Here, `account.trips` is a list of `Trip` object and `AddNewTrip` is the 'add' card.
Because of my `if`, the first element of the list is always not displayed

So, is there another way to put my 'add' card as the first element of the list, without hiding one element ?

```
return Builder(
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    if (account.trips.indexOf(i) == 0) {
      return new AddNewTrip(account);
    }
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
         top: 20.0, bottom: 40.0, left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
           child: Stack(
        ...
```

EDIT : here is the full code :

```
Expanded(
          child: ScopedModelDescendant<Account>(
            builder: (context, child, _account){
              print(_account.profile);
              return new CarouselSlider(
                enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                initialPage: 1,
                items: itemBuilder(_account)
              );
            },
          ),
        )
```

```
List<Widget> itemBuilder(Account account) {
      if (account.trips != null)
        return account.trips.map((i) {
          return Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              if (account.trips.indexOf(i) == 0) {
                return new AddNewTrip(account);
              }
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 20.0, bottom: 40.0, left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Hero(
                      tag: i.id,
                      child: Material(
                        type: MaterialType.transparency,
                        child: InkWell(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 200,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                            decoration: cardImage(i.imageUrl),
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context)
                                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                              return TripDetails(i);
                            }));
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.48,
                      top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                      left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.035,
                      child: Hero(
                        tag: i.id + 'container', //should be an ID
                        child: Material(
                          type: MaterialType.transparency,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: cardDecoration,
                            child: new TripContent(i, true),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }).toList();
      else
      return [
        new AddNewTrip(account)
      ];
    }
```

Comment: what is the parent/container of the builder

Comment: My builder is the child of the `items` property of the Carousel Slider : https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answers already provide a good general advice on how to do this.
For your specific example you would have to do something like this:

When looping over your accounts, prepend the result with your "Add" card like this:

```dart
List<Widget> itemBuilder(Account account) {
  return [
    new AddNewTrip(account),
    ...(account.trips?.map((i) {/** same as before without your index check **/}) ?? []),
  ];
}
```

Comment: What does the three points mean ? and did you voluntarily take off the .toList ?

Comment: This is the new spread operator (which does not require `toList()`) in dart 2.3, you can read more about it here: https://medium.com/flutter-community/whats-new-in-dart-2-3-1a7050e2408d

Answer (score 1):

```
return account.trips.map((i) {
```

change to:

```
return [[null], account.trips].expand((x) => x).toList().map((i) {
```

Comment: Well, as it is not really a ListView builder, I don't know if it applies to it. I'm going to edit my post with the full code.

Comment: I don't understand the second line :O

Comment: the second line is used to create new list with null value at index 0

Answer (score 1):

how about this you build the card first then build rest of your list..

```
  List<Widget> itemBuilder(Account account) {
   return [
    AddNewTrip(account),
    if (account.trips != null)
     return account.trips.map((i) {
       return Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Padding(
             //rest of your code
            );
        });
    );
 }];}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dummy list item in your list at `0th` index and later you can perform your logic.

Below is sample code can help you out:

```
  var list = ["1","3","4"];
  list.insert(0,"5");
```

Output:`5 1 3 4`

Comment: The thing is that the 0th element (the add card) is completly different from the other elements of the list :/ With my list, I am building -with the builder- other widgets

Comment: You can pass the static dummy data.